# Parse SQL Query into Multiple Scripts with Python

Tags: python, sql, parsing, split

I have a sql query compose of 56k lines. You may find the summary of it in the below.
I like to parse the sql query into multiple ones. I've tried sqlparse and some other methods, however those would'nt helped. I think it's because there are so many subqueries in my main query and no seperator like (;).

Any help would be appreciated!

```
/* Formatted on 14/09/2022 08:03:20 (QP5 v5.256.13226.35538) */
  SELECT t1.title,
         t1.emp_name,
         t1.emp_surname,
         c1.fee,
         (SELECT m.average_prc
            FROM market m
           WHERE m.title = t1.title)
            market_price
    FROM employees t1, costs c1
   WHERE t1.emp_name = t2.emp_name
GROUP BY t1.title, t1.emp_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.title,
         t1.emp_name,
         t1.emp_surname,
         c1.fee,
         (SELECT m.average_prc
            FROM engineers m
           WHERE m.title = t1.title
          UNION ALL
          SELECT t.average_prc
            FROM teachers t
           WHERE t.title = t1.title)
            market_price
    FROM employees_engineers t1, costs c1
   WHERE t1.emp_name = t2.emp_name
GROUP BY t1.title, t1.emp_name
/* this is just summary, it has many lot tables and columns */
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I like to have multiple sql queries from this big query and that sould have done with python parsing or splitting ...

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to extract each subquery as a single query? How do you represent an extracted query that has other subqueries itself? Please post a list of strings, with each string a subquery from your main query.

Comment: Actually I like to set the query apart from UNION parts. As there are many UNIONS both in master query and subqueries, that also not working properly.